# Use GET variable to choose a array without using an IF statement for everything

Tags: php

I'm doing a script that involves choosing a random string from an array and redirecting to it (using headers). I want it so that using a get variable and it will load the array with the same name as it. So, if the get variable is random, then it would load the array random and use that.

Does that make sense?

I'm using for a random avatar script, so that it will get a username then choose the array for that username, then select a random avatar URL.

Comment: How can it choose which array to use based on the $_GET['username'] (without doing an if statement for each one that you want to set)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP supports "variable variables", so you could do something like:

```
$arrayName = $_GET['username'];
$arr = $$arrayName;
```

So, if you had an array defined in your script:

```
$bill = array(1, 2);
```

and the value of `$_GET['username']` is `'bill'`, then `$bill` would be copied to `$arr` by the above.

For more see [this documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

Comment: So, how would that work? (Sorry I'm kinda new to PHP) As in, how would that choose the array?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
$avatars = array(
    'alex' => array('avatar1.jpg', 'avatar2.jpg', 'avatar3.jpg'),
    'bob' => array('avatar4.jpg', 'avatar5.jpg', 'avatar6.jpg'),
    'crissa' => array('avatar7.jpg', 'avatar8.jpg', 'avatar9.jpg'),
);

$username = $_GET['username'];

if (isset($avatars[$username])) {
    $avatar = $avatars[$username][mt_rand(0, count($avatars[$username]) - 1)];
    header('Location: ' . $avatar);
}
```